# How to arrange data in array by month and year

Tags: php, zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I am developing one website in php zend framework and sql server 2008.

I need to make one multidimensional array which stores the data by year and month in this format :

```
Array(
  [2012] => Array(
      [11] => Array(           
         // data
    )
      [12] => Array(
        // data
      )

  )

  [2013] => Array(
      [01] => Array(           
         // data
    )
      [02] => Array(
        // data
      )
      [03] => Array(           
         // data
    )
      [04] => Array(
        // data
      )
  )
)
```

But i am getting duplicates in my result array. Means i am getting 2012 data in 2013 also.
My code is as follows :

```
 // Database functions to get data

 function select_cldata($month,$year)
    {
      global $db;
       $select = "select ClientId,ClientName,Email,Request,'Order Placed' as info from tbl_clrequest where MONTH(CreatedDate) = ".$month." and YEAR(CreatedDate) = ".$year;
       return $db->fetchAll($select);
    }

function select_itemsdata($month,$year)
{
   global $db;
   $select = "select ItemId,ItemName,Desc,price,'Items delivered' as info1 from tbl_items where MONTH(ItemDate) = ".$month." and YEAR(ItemDate) = ".$year;
   return $db->fetchAll($select);
}

// PHP Code
$test = new dbase();
$months = "2012-11,2012-12,2013-01,2013-02,2013-03,2013-04";
$mon_num = explode(",",$months);
$res = array();
$result = array();
foreach($mon_num as $mn)
{   
    $mm = explode("-",$mn);
    $year = $mm[0];
    $month = $mm[1];
    $cl_data = $test->select_cldata($month,$year);
    $dl_data = $test->select_itemsdata($month,$year);
    $res[$month] = array_merge($clients,$sr,$events,$ses,$docs,$event_change,$devents);
    $result[$year] = $res;  
}
echo "<pre>";                               
print_r($result);die;
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: are you sure `select_cldata()` is returning correct data?

Comment: Yes i am sure. Its something wrong in the process of array only. But i cant find what is it.

Comment: From where the arrays `$clients,$sr,$events,$ses,$docs, $event_change,$devents` creating.

Comment: can you try this `$result[$year][$month] = array_merge($clients,..);`

Answer (score 0):

below is your solution with my working example

```
foreach($mon_num as $mn)
{   
    $mm = explode("-",$mn);    
    $year = $mm[0];
    $month = $mm[1];
    $cl_data = $test->select_cldata($month,$year);
    $dl_data = $test->select_itemsdata($month,$year);
    $res = array_merge($clients,$sr,$events,$ses,$docs,$event_change,$devents);
    $result[$year][$month] = $res;  
}
```

i have added some dummy data to print

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [2012] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [01] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

            [02] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

            [03] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

            [04] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 1211
                    [2] => 112122
                    [3] => 121111
                    [4] => 67676
                    [5] => 545454
                    [6] => 666666
                )

        )

)
```

hope this will sure solve your issue.